# TravisCI.yml for iOS, destination not correct

Tags: ios, travis-ci, xcodebuild

I have a simple iOS app that I want to use in Travis CI. I use a matrix with `TEST_SDK` and `TEST_DESTINATION`. However, the destination doesn't seem to work properly.

This is my .travis.yml:

```
language: objective-c
osx_image: xcode9.2
cache: cocoapods
before_install:
  - pod repo update
  - pod update
env:
  matrix:
    - TEST_SDK=iphonesimulator11.1 TEST_DESTINATION="platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 7 Plus,OS=11.1"
    - TEST_SDK=iphonesimulator11.2 TEST_DESTINATION="platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 7 Plus,OS=11.2"
script:
  - xcodebuild test -workspace iOSApp.xcworkspace -scheme iOSApp -sdk $TEST_SDK -destination $TEST_DESTINATION | xcpretty
```

The problem is that when I run the script locally, I get this output: `xcodebuild: error: Unknown build action '7'.`

When I run `xcodebuild test -workspace iOS.xcworkspace -scheme iOS -sdk $TEST_SDK -destination platform="iOS Simulator",name="iPhone 7 Plus",OS=11.2 | xcpretty` it works fine.

Therefore, I replaced the .travis.yml with : `- TEST_SDK=iphonesimulator11.2 TEST_DESTINATION=platform="iOS Simulator",name="iPhone 7 Plus",OS=11.2` for example. However, this errors again with `xcodebuild: error: Unknown build action '7'.`

How can I get this to work correctly?

Comment: try using `TEST_DESTINATION="platform='iOS Simulator',name='iPhone 7 Plus',OS=11.1"`

Comment: @Mukesh It still errors out for me, saying `xcodebuild: error: Unknown build action '7'`

Comment: @Mukesh I'm testing that locally, before pushing it to CI. I'm just setting `export TEST_DESTINATION="platform='iOS Simulator',name='iPhone 7 Plus',OS=11.1"`

Comment: Sorry my bad just use `TEST_DESTINATION="'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 7 Plus,OS=11.1'"`. See the single quotes at start and end.  `export TEST_DESTINATION="'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 7 Plus,OS=11.1'"`

Comment: `xcodebuild: error: option 'Destination' requires at least one parameter of the form 'key=value'`

Comment: This is so annoying, haha. It's such an idiot idea of Apple to have people use `iPhone 7 Plus` instead of  `iphone7plus` for example

Comment: Do you maybe have another idea, @Mukesh?

Comment: I got it working with this   `export TEST_DESTINATION="platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 7 Plus,OS=11.1"` and for the build use TEST_DESTINATION in double quotes like `xcodebuild test -workspace iOSApp.xcworkspace -scheme iOSApp -sdk $TEST_SDK -destination "$TEST_DESTINATION"`

Comment: Let me know if it works.

Comment: That worked, you are such a hero! :) Please add your answer as answer, then I can award you the bounty!

Comment: @Mukesh It works perfectly fine :D

Comment: Glad it worked :). I have added the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working with this:

`export TEST_DESTINATION="platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 7 Plus,OS=11.1"`

and for the build use TEST_DESTINATION in double quotes like

```
xcodebuild test -workspace iOSApp.xcworkspace -scheme iOSApp -sdk $TEST_SDK -destination "$TEST_DESTINATION" | xcpretty
```